# R - Change position of geom_text inside geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to control the position of two calls of `geom_text` inside `geom_bar`, but I just can't get it right.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

However, I would like to change two things in this plot:

1. Put the letters (first geom_text call) at the top left corner of the bars, just before the error bars. Or perhaps on top of the error bars.
2. Put the numbers (second geom_text call) in the middle of the bars.

Here are my code and dataset sample:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- structure(list(ObservationId = c("Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control"
), Treatment = c("TREATMENT A", "TREATMENT B", "UNTREATED", "TREATMENT A", 
"TREATMENT B", "UNTREATED", "TREATMENT A", "TREATMENT B", "UNTREATED"
), day_class = c("Time1", "Time1", "Time1", "Time2", "Time2", 
"Time2", "Time3", "Time3", "Time3"), Estimate = c(100, 99.8, 
0.7, 97.2, 91.2, 7.2, 94.6, 87.3, 14.5), SE = c(4.2, 4.4, 3.7, 
3.6, 4.1, 3.8, 3.7, 4.1, 3.8), df = c(38.5, 42.3, 37.4, 33.5, 
37.4, 37.8, 33.9, 38.5, 38.1), lower.CL = c(91.6, 90.9, -6.9, 
89.8, 83, -0.4, 87.2, 79, 6.9), upper.CL = c(108.4, 108.7, 8.3, 
104.6, 99.5, 14.8, 102.1, 95.7, 22.1), Class = c("A", "A", "B", 
"A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = Treatment,
           y = Estimate,
           group = day_class,
           fill = day_class)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL,
                    ymax = upper.CL),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Class, group = day_class),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            color = 'blue',
            size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Estimate,1), group = day_class),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            size = 4)
```

How can I achieve those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hjust` and `vjust` offers flexibility to nudge labels:

```
<as your code> +
     geom_text(aes(label = Class, group = day_class),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                color = 'blue',
                hjust = 4, vjust = -3,
                size = 5) +                
      geom_text(aes(label = round(Estimate,1), group = day_class),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2,
                size = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `y` inside `geom_text`, an example:

```
ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = Treatment,
           y = Estimate,
           group = day_class,
           fill = day_class)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL,
                    ymax = upper.CL),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Class, group = day_class,y = upper.CL),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            color = 'blue',
            size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Estimate,1), group = day_class, y = (upper.CL+Estimate)/2 ),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            size = 4)
```

[image]